# How to save SVN user name or Password?

Tags: android, svn

How to save at once user name or password in windows tortoise SVN, Instead of typing every time filling the user name or password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really should show you something like this when you need to authenticate.

[image]

Then just check that **Save authentication** box and it is saved.

**EDIT**: In case you are using TortoisePlink, try this:

`path_to_TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -l username_here -pw password_here`

where -l is user and -pw is password

Also check the [Plink parameters list](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage)

Comment: In my case check box is not coming. once takes user name and then asks for password. using TortoisePlink